# Censoring and then re-entering subjects

Tags: survival, bias

I am following a group of woman during the study period and performing the analysis using Cox model, comparing non-users against users of the investigated medicine. However, to remove the impact of pregnancy on the response (stroke), my plan is to censor both users and non-users during pregnancy, and restart their follow-up time after delivery. In case a woman experiences stroke during pregnancy, she does not re-enter study after delivery.

I am wondering if this is a legitimate way of performing the analysis or should I be worried about survivorship bias due to risk-free time during pregnancy for women that re-entered the study?

Comment: Is this an observational or randomized study? Is the treatment in question a birth control or another medication that should be discontinued during pregnancy?

Comment: It is an observational study. The treatment is birth control.

Comment: Before you conclude that censoring patients is absolutely necessary, consider that there may be lagged effects of treatment. The mechanism of stroke is not well known, and all evidence points to a slow progression/cumulative risk of cardiovascular morbidities (silent infarcts, microvascular damage, coronary artery calcification). So I would choose one as a primary analysis, and another as a "sensitivity analysis".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods (interval censoring women during pregnancy vs. including them as at-risk during pregnancy) correspond to different hypotheses and different inferences. Put simply, in scenario one the hypothesis is that your medicine affects the stroke risk in women who are not pregnant, in scenario two the hypothesis is that the medicine affects stroke risk in women.

Contraindications in pregnancy is even more subtle than this. If a patient is advised to discontinue a treatment after becoming pregnant, you can liken the comparison to an intent-to-treat analysis versus a per-protocol analysis. Typically, we expect the treatment effects to be higher in a per-protocol analysis and analysis set, but this is not guaranteed (see the controversy over the Astrazeneca COVID19 vaccine analysis).